# Formating a date field in the Model (Codeigniter)

Tags: date, codeigniter, model

I', trying to re-format a date from a table in Codeigniter. The Controller is for a blog. I was succesfull when the date conversion happens in the View. I was hoping to convert the date in the Model to have things in order.

This is the Model:

```
    class Novedades_model extends Model {

 function getAll() {
  $this->db->order_by('date','desc'); 
  $query = $this->db->get('novedades');

  if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
   foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
   }
  }
  return $data;
 }
}
```

This is part of the controller

```
$this->load->model('novedades_model');
$data['records'] = $this->novedades_model->getAll();
```

Here's the date conversion as it happens in the View. This is inside the posts loop:

```
 <?php foreach($records as $row) : ?>

  <?php 
   $fdate = "%d <abbr>%M</abbr> %Y";
   $dateConv = mdate($fdate, mysql_to_unix($row->date));
  ?>

  <div class="article section">
   <span class="date"><?php echo $dateConv ;?></span>
```

... Keeps going ...

How can I convert the date in the Model? Can I access the date key and refactor it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why you need to format the date in the Model because ultimately you need the formatted date in the View to be shown.* However, you can do the same what you are already doing in the View for formatting it:

```
 function getAll() {
  $this->db->order_by('date','desc'); 
  $query = $this->db->get('novedades');

  if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
   foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
   }
  }

  foreach($data as $row) :
   $fdate = "%d <abbr>%M</abbr> %Y";
   $dateConv = mdate($fdate, mysql_to_unix($row->date));
   ............

 }
```